# Why is Symfony's autowire giving me the debug-version instance of a class? Can I bypass this to get the regular version in dev mode?

Tags: php, symfony, mercure

I have a problem with the autowiring of Symfony\Component\Mercure\Publisher. Instead I am being autowired Symfony\Component\Mercure\Debug\TraceablePublisher by error. How do I fix this?

**Error message is:**
 Argument 1 passed to App\Controller\PublisherController::index() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Mercure\Publisher, instance of Symfony\Component\Mercure\Debug\TraceablePublisher given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\freely\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php on line 145

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\Publisher;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\Update;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class PublisherController
 * @package App\Controller  
 */
class PublisherController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/publish/{topic}", name="publisher", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function index(Publisher $publisher, $topic, Request $request)
    {
        $publisher(new Update($topic, $request->getContent()));
        return new Response('success');
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "<3 to be working with Mercure soon!" mean? Please add your error message to your question and delete your comment. You can edit your question at all times.

Comment: Fixed it by simply switching from dev to prod temporarily

Comment: Glad you got it working but just type hint against PublisherInterface and the problem will go away.

Comment: Fixed it with PublisherInterface